# Connection, Formal property not understood

Tags: derivatives, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I do not formally understand this (last,4th) property of the linear connection:

$\nabla_{fX}Y=f\nabla_XY$.

What (object) do we formally get by applying a function $f\in C^\infty(M)$

to the vector field $\nabla_XY$?

Even what is $f(Z)$ for a vector field $Z$ on the manifold $M$ would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a vector field. A vector field $X$ on the manifold $M$ is defined by a differentiable map $X:M\rightarrow TM$ where $TM$ is the tangent bundle, recall that $p:TM\rightarrow M$ is a vector bundle, so $p^{-1}(x)=T_xM$ is a vector space, so you can define $(fX)(x)=f(x)X(x)$.

Comment: Did we use somewhere in your explanation that $p\circ X=id_M$ ?